# Fresh HDD on my laptop

Tags: boot, hard-drive, laptop

So I had to get a new HDD for my laptop and I am deciding to go with a full Ubuntu OS. I am a windows user. Figured I'd try something new and besides I have a desktop... Anyways I have a Ubuntu install disk. Can I just insert that into the laptop and it should open? Or is is there more steps I should follow (I still have yet to buy a new HDD that's why I have not tried).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are going to need to access the UEFI/BIOS on your machine via one of the function keys (it varies per manufacturer). To install Ubuntu, you MUST disable secure boot in the BIOS settings. Then, you can either change the boot order in your BIOS settings so that the USB disk or CD ROM boots first or simply select it in the boot devices menu. That's about it...